# How to use generic Google Maps Icons in Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, icons

I want to use certain generic Google Maps Icons in my Android Application. I dont know how to access them like this:

```
userMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(..???...));
```

Any suggestions on how to access the generic Map Icons in Google Maps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// latitude and longitude
double latitude = 17.385044;
double longitude = 78.486671;
 
// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");
 
// Changing marker icon
marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon)));
 
// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

More more info :

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

---

## update

float   HUE_AZURE
float   HUE_BLUE
float   HUE_CYAN
float   HUE_GREEN
float   HUE_MAGENTA
float   HUE_ORANGE
float   HUE_RED
float   HUE_ROSE
float   HUE_VIOLET
float   HUE_YELLOW

do check them http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed tutorial.  Are there more icons accessible, not only the colored pins (HUE_RED, HUE_VIOLET, ...)?

Comment: I guess this answers my question. If I want to have icons I need to add them myself.

Comment: I also found a nice video on markers on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3bw8Senjmg